# Unable to find necessary user location graphical assets (MapBox)

Tags: ios5, geolocation, ios6

Do we need to manually import in main project the user location graphical assets from iOS MapBox SDK ?

If I try to show user location, I've got this error (built on iPhone 4s on iOS6 — same error is logged on simulator iOS 5.1)

```
if (!self.mapView.isUserLocationVisible) {
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
```

The exact error logged is :

> [RMUserLocation initWithMapView:coordinate:andTitle:], /Users/franco/Apps/XXXX/Application/XXXX/Vendors/mapbox-ios-sdk/MapView/Map/RMUserLocation.m:24
>   2012-06-13 01:41:52.426 XXXX[2058:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to find necessary user location graphical assets (copy from MapView/Map/Resources)'

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution found, is to **add (copy) assets files from MapView/Map/Resources to my root project**.

I thought the Header Search Paths (set to **$(SRCROOT)/IntraMuros/Vendors/mapbox-ios-sdk**) would make these assets available.

There is probably a cleaner way to do this.

Note that assets files are available in the MapView sub-project.

Comment: I'll let you guys find a real solution to this problem, without having to import assets in the root project.
I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of the SDK. There's not an easier solution, since the SDK builds as a static library and as such, can't contain graphical assets. One thing that you can do is just reference the assets, not necessarily copy them into your project, and use the actual files shipped with the SDK. But I put that `NSAssert()` in to avoid a situation where the dev wouldn't know why the user location wasn't showing up.

I should also add that, like Apple's MapKit, the `isUserLocationVisible` property is not for testing if the location is shown, but rather if it's on screen currently. So you should instead check `showsUserLocation` to determine whether to set `showsUserLocation`.